QGIS attribute table keep track of modifcation date (of individual records)
In QGIS, I'd like to keep track of when a record was created and when it was last modified.
I've tried using field calculator and now() function, but it seems to work only once and subsequent alterations are not updated. Is there a relatively simple way to achieve my goal?
(table is saved in geopackage)

For this, I suggest creating two fields:
creationDate, and latestUpdate.
To make it work nicely, go to Layer Properties, and select “Attributes form”.
Select the field creationDate. In its properties:

Disable the 'editable' option,
Set widget type to 'Date/time',
Set the display format to your preference,
Disable options 'calendar popup' and 'Allow NULL values',
In the 'Defaults' section, set 'Default value' to 'now()'. This will add a date, according to the format set in 3.
Disable option 'Apply default value on update', This will ensure that the default value will only be applied if the field is empty, i.e., on the creation date.

Now, select the latestUpdate field, and repeat steps 1 to 5. For step 6, enable the option "Apply default value on update". The field will be updated anytime the record is changed, keeping the date of the last update.
These settings will work both in the form and the table views.

